# Binding any bootstrap to dynamic HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, binding

My question is not about binding a single event to a specific DOM element. My question is, how can you rebind your whole bootstrap library to dynamically generated DOM elements?

For my case I am using the Jquery method .load and I would like to rebind the HTML loaded by that method to my Metro UI bootstrap library. I don't think going to the loaded HTML, checking all the events and components used and re-binding them is an effective solution. I might as well prefer somehow refreshing all bindings after loading the dynamic HTML (if that is also possible). Any help there? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After a while of trying I finally found a way to execute the script. I added another method to the callback function to the .load method:

```
$("#id").load( "dynamic.html", function(){
    $.getScript("boostrap.js");
} );
```

It may not be the most effective way to rebind elements, but at least I make sure all the JS code is re-binded as if the HTML had been loaded from the initial load.